# Spring Unit Testing: Autowire the Implementation of an Interface directly?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

Our Spring webapp implements a lot of autowired Interfaces. Some of the methods in an implementation of an interface do a lot. There is a public point of entry into the method itself and much of the logic is abstracted into lots of private methods. Unit and Integration tests are pretty bulky as a result since there is a lot to test for. In terms of writing integration tests I was considering a pattern of having the test Autowire the *implemention* rather than the interface, changing the scope of these private methods to public, but not exposing them to the owning interface.

This would allow for unit testing these subroutines, while keeping the contract clean of lots of methods that no one would use outside of the scope of the service itself.

Is this a known pattern? What are the drawbacks to this approach?

Comment: It's my understanding that it's actually more beneficial to test the service implementations rather than just the interface. One way to do it would be to use implementations as parameters in unit tests, this way you only care about the contract. Since unit testing does not need to cover everything this should usually be enough. However, if you also want ot test stuff outside the contract I'm not sure a standard approach has been designated. But do go ahead with testing implementations.

Comment: thanks- if you want to log this as an answer I'll give it the check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my understanding that it's actually more beneficial to test the service implementations rather than just the interface.

One way to do it would be to use implementations as parameters in unit tests, this way you only care about the contract.

Since unit testing does not need to cover everything this should usually be enough.

However, if you also want to test stuff outside the contract I'm not sure a standard approach has been designated. But do go ahead with testing implementations.